# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'school_id' cannot be null

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, post

When I try to post my data to the api in Json format I get the error:

> "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'school_id' cannot be null"

This is my js (vuejs)

```
if (this.editD === false) {
    fetch('/api/school/'+this.location.school_id+'/location/store', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.location),
        header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.emptyLocation();
        this.editD = false;
        this.fetchSchools();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I tried returning the body value that is being send to verify that it is a valid Json format and it is:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "school_id": 1,
    "department_name": "test",
    "department_address": "etst",
    "department_zip": "ttest",
    "department_city": "set",
    "department_phone": "32324"
}
```

My Api route looks like this:

```
Route::post('/school/{id}/location/store', 'Owner\ApiController@storeLocation');
```

And the Controller Method like this:

```
public function storeLocation(request $request) {

    $department = new Department;
    $department->school_id = $request->input('school_id');
    $department->department_name = $request->input('department_name');
    $department->department_address = $request->input('department_address');
    $department->department_zip = $request->input('department_zip');
    $department->department_city = $request->input('department_city');
    $department->department_phone = $request->input('department_phone');

    if($department->save()) {
        return new Department($department);
    }

}
```

When doing this Post with the same parameters (but not in json) in Postmen it does insert it into the db but I get the following error:

> "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, object given"

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because you are newing up a `Department` before its given a school_id

```
public function storeLocation(request $request) {

    $department = Department::create($request->all());

    return $department;
}
```

Also make sure your Department model has the following

```
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'school_id',
        'department_name',
        'department_address',
        'department_zip',
        'department_city',
        'department_phone',
    ];
```

The code you have provided also returns a new department even after creating one.

EDIT:

try modifying your post to the following

```
    const location = this.location;
    fetch('/api/school/'+this.location.school_id+'/location/store', {
        method: 'post',
        body: {
           ...location,
        },
        header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
```

Comment: Changed the method to your code and added the mass assignable attributes. Now I get this error: General error: 1364 Field 'school_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `department` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-12-04 22:57:29, 2019-12-04 22:57:29)

Comment: what happens when you `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Its empty. It returns: []

Comment: @rubex01 I have updated my answer, I think its because you are stringifying the post, it should still be an object.

Comment: How can I send an object as body if the header content-type is still application/json. When having the object as body it says the payload is [object Object]

Comment: Have you tried changing 'content-type': 'application/json' to 'Accept': 'application/json' inside your json request